# How can I build my own customzied code snippet?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, code-snippets

I want to build my own code snippet for C# windows form application.

It all over the internet concerning the ASP.NET MVC and none of it is talking about C# windows forms or is it the same process of dealing with XML.

Well thank you guys for reading my question and helping me about it and wish you good luck in your job or college.

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial about how you can create your own code snippets for any kind of project. Also, in part 2 literals are explained (they are like variables in code snippets). [How to: Create your own code snippet - Start Debugging](http://startdebugging.net/how-to-create-your-own-code-snippet/) By the end of that article you will have created a code snippet for Silverlight dependency properties.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio code snippets are platform-independent.

You can use or create the same code snippets for any kind of project.

Comment: Well I know that man but how do you get to the code snippet file    it self so that you can customize it according to your own preference - so later on I can import it to my projects and it is changeable - So I can start having my own code snippets library that can save time when building projects - like to be more specific about it is it the same process like in ASP.NET do you have to deal with XML - I am still rookie at it and learning at college but I want to start building my own codes so I can have more effort in code learning process and trying it for real life project during summer 4 ex

Comment: Code snippets are not per-project.  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

They are located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#

(The fileextensions are .snippet)

See "Creating and Using IntelliSense Code Snippets":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Snippet Designer](http://snippetdesigner.codeplex.com/) provides an easy way to access and modify snippets.

The Snippet Explorer tool window is located under View -> Other Windows -> Snippet Explorer.